Xiao esp23c3 core dump flash config is corrupted when code apparents being correct
So I've been using a simple state design pattern for a xiao esp32c3 chip, and upon uploading the code, my state machine works kinda fine, except the fact that in the first state I get spammed with the following:
Rebooting...
ESP-ROM:esp32c3-api1-20210207
Build:Feb  7 2021
rst:0x3 (RTC_SW_SYS_RST),boot:0xe (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x40048b82
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fcd5820,len:0xf64
load:0x403cc710,len:0x73c
load:0x403ce710,len:0x2eac
entry 0x403cc710
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Store access fault). Exception was unhandled.

Core  0 register dump:
MEPC    : 0x4038608c  RA      : 0x40386a0c  SP      : 0x3fcde250  GP      : 0x3fc8c200
TP      : 0x00000000  T0      : 0x4005890e  T1      : 0x40386292  T2      : 0x00000000
S0/FP   : 0x000007d0  S1      : 0x3fc8e000  A0      : 0x00000000  A1      : 0x00000000
A2      : 0x00000003  A3      : 0x00000008  A4      : 0x3fc8e000  A5      : 0x00000000
A6      : 0x00010000  A7      : 0x40384416  S2      : 0x3c034000  S3      : 0x00000000
S4      : 0x0000edd8  S5      : 0x3c030000  S6      : 0xffff0000  S7      : 0x4038133e
S8      : 0x00020020  S9      : 0x00010020  S10     : 0x00000005  S11     : 0x3fcde3c0
T3      : 0x3fc8fa38  T4      : 0xffff0000  T5      : 0x00000000  T6      : 0x00000000
MSTATUS : 0x00001881  MTVEC   : 0x40380001  MCAUSE  : 0x00000007  MTVAL   : 0x00000152
MHARTID : 0x00000000 

(stack memory displays here memory adresses... and then this)

ELF file SHA256: 8a3e19fac03e38d8

E (429) esp_core_dump_flash: Core dump flash config is corrupted! CRC=0x7bd5c66f instead of 0x0
E (437) esp_core_dump_elf: Elf write init failed!
E (442) esp_core_dump_common: Core dump write failed with error=-1

This error loops while in the first state, until i write in the serial monitor the input to switch states, which usually works. THe looping with the "Waiting for input" from the first state and the error is asynchronous.
This is my chip.cpp
#include "chip.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <string>

chip::chip()
    : reading_pin(D0), power_pin(D2), pwmFreq(5000), pwmResolution(8), 
     idleState(), pairedState(), genState(), currentState(&idleState){
    

    delayMicroseconds(1000); // Stabilize serial 


    pinMode(reading_pin, INPUT);
    ledcAttach(power_pin, pwmFreq, pwmResolution);

}


void chip::loop() {
    this->performState();
    this->handle(); // checks serial monitor for requests
    //this->printchip();

}

void chip::performState(){
    if (currentState == nullptr) {
        Serial.println("Error: Current state is null.");
        return;
    }
    currentState->perform(this);
}

void chip::handle() {
    if (currentState == nullptr) {
        Serial.println("Error: Current state is null.");
        return;
    }
    currentState->handleRequest(this);

}

void chip::setState(State* newState) {

    if (newState == nullptr) {
        Serial.println("Error: Attempted to set state to null.");
        return;
    }

    currentState = newState; // change states

}

/*
void chip::printchip(){
  currentState->printState();

}*/

And my IdleState.cpp, which inherits from state.h
#include "idlestate.h"
#include "chip.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

void IdleState::perform(chip* esp) {
  

    Serial.println("Waiting for HANDSHAKE input...");
    delayMicroseconds(1000); // Let the user see the message 
}

void IdleState::handleRequest(chip* esp) {
  
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        String input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

        if (input.equals("HANDSHAKE")){
            
            // blink as sucessfull handshake
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                esp->ledWrite(255);
                delay(100); 
                esp->ledWrite(0);
                delay(100);
                esp->ledWrite(255);
                delay(100);
                esp->ledWrite(0);
                delay(100);
            }
            Serial.println("Comms established! Device paired.\nWaiting for GEN input");
            esp->setState(&esp->pairedState);
        }
        else{
            Serial.println("Invalid input for current state of the chip");
            return;
        }
    }
    
}
/*
void IdleState::printState(){
  Serial.println("GAGAA");
}*/

So by commenting out functions i found the problem was in the chip's loop function, and for the error not to happen i had to comment out this->performState() and this->handle(). Even if i commented their bodies, the error would still occur. I tried seeing if this issue was about accessing currentState's functions,by creating the dummy function "printState()", and it indeed keeps printing this error. My main.ino file is this:
#include "chip.h"
#include "Arduino.h"



chip babelChip;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);// BAUD HERE
    babelChip = chip();
}

void loop(){
    babelChip.loop();
}

Keep in mind somehow the state machine works. I've tried everything for the last 2 days from debugging with other people to analyzing every line with chatgpt, which makes me think this is either a super niche error or a hardware issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

"this is either a super niche error or a hardware issue", this is neither niche nor hardware, 1) The babelChip = chip() is a useless line that created a local instance that never been used outside of the setup() function; 2) When chip babelChip is run before setup() and loop(), it create an instance and the chip::chip() is executed, due to the Arduino Framework design, you are running code even before some of the initialisation is done in the main.cpp.


For Arduino, don't execute any code such as configuring peripheral in the class construct, move those code into a method begin() and call it within the setup() to set up the peripherals. So in summary, change your Class construct design and create a begin() (or init()) method, replace babelChip = chip() with babelChip.begin().


You might have other problems with your design of the state machine, and don't know how you invoke the state machine, or how you create an instance of IdleState class, so can't comment much.

I also had a Guru Meditation Error when moving to the ESP32S3 from a plain ESP32 and spent days tracking it down.
Its more likely to be a coding error than a configuration setting - my code had run perfectly previously but it turned out I had introduced errors during the change.
The first thing I found was that Serial.println() messages weren't appearing, and I needed to add a delay in setup() as shown here.
The actual problem was then found by scrutinising my code in detail, and adding some assertions. Look first of all at your global int variables and make sure they have the value you expect when you use them.
I had initialised a value when declaring with
int myInt = 0;

and by using
assert ("myInt error at line __LINE__", myInt != 0)

it turned out myInt had not been set before getting to
  return ((aValue >= 0) && (aValue < myInt));

which caused the Guru Meditation Error.
